# Idea of Dirac operator on quantum groups

Tags: oa.operator-algebras, kt.k-theory-and-homology, quantum-groups, dirac-operator

This is a somewhat unexact question. I would like to now more on the principle of the Dirac operator, especially for quantum groups.

I have learned in some articles about the Dirac operator on the quantum Podles sphere, $SL_q(U_n)$, and compact quantum groups. For example, in one construction one roughly speaking pulls back the classical Dirac operator of Lie groups to quantum groups via some isomorphism by Drinfeld.
On other constructions one uses the classical Clifford algebra, which shows up in a tensor factor.

My question and problem is:

How can I construct a Dirac operator for a given quantum group? It may not be easy, but is there some guiding principle?

How can I construct, if possible, a kind of dual Dirac operator (Bott element), as done by Kasparov in his 1988 paper? Is there some idea or principle I have to know?

I know this question may appear to vague. But maybe one can say more about the principle about Dirac operators and dual Dirac operators, especially for quantum groups.